# Trouble with image upload {Ajax,php,Filereader}

Tags: php, ajax, filereader, image-upload

When I upload the image the server return "empty".

What i need to change from server or client to work?
I want to upload only one image and i dont have form etc
HTML:

input id="imgupload" type="file" value="Upload"

Client Side:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
                            function readURL(input) {
                                var fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
                                var extension = input.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),
                                    isSuccess = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;
                                if (isSuccess) {
                                    reader.onload = function (e)
                                    {
                                        $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
                                        $('#imguploadinput').hide();
                                        $('#imguploadmenu').show();
                                        $( "#imgsave" ).click(function() {
                                            imagesave(e.target.result);
                                        });
                                    }
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                                }
                                else{
                                    imagedelete();
                                    $('#error').html("file error!");
                                }
                            }
                            function imagesave(img){
                                //$('#imguploadmenu').hide();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "system/profile/uploadimage.php",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {img:img},
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        $("#imgSpinner1").hide();
                                        $('#error').html(data);
                                    },
                                    beforeSend: function() {
                                        $("#imgSpinner1").show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

Server Side:

```
$imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
if ($imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/png") || $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/jpeg")
    || $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/gif") ||
    $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/bmp")) {
    echo "ok";
    }
else
{
    if(empty($_FILES['img'])) echo "empty";
    else echo "no empty";
}
```